# java - Unable to run programs utilising sockets (Unable to connect and listen failed)

Tags: java

I have two classes - Provider and Requester:

**Provider**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class Provider {
    ServerSocket providerSocket;
    Socket connection = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    String message;

    Provider() {
    }

    void run() {
        try {
            // 1. creating a server socket
            providerSocket = new ServerSocket(2004, 10);
            // 2. Wait for connection
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection");
            connection = providerSocket.accept();
            System.out.println(
                    "Connection received from " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
            // 3. get Input and Output streams
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            sendMessage("Connection successful");
            // 4. The two parts communicate via the input and output streams
            do {
                try {
                    sendMessage(
                            "Please enter the phrase you wish to echo or the word FINISHED to exit");

                    message = (String) in.readObject();

                    sendMessage(message);

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException classnot) {
                    System.err.println("Data received in unknown format");
                }
            } while (!message.equals("FINISHED"));
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // 4: Closing connection
            try {
                in.close();
                out.close();
                providerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    void sendMessage(String msg) {
        try {
            out.writeObject(msg);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println("server>" + msg);
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Provider server = new Provider();
        while (true) {
            server.run();
        }
    }
}
```

**Requester**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Requester {
    Socket requestSocket;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    String message;
    Scanner input;

    Requester() {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    void run() {
        try {
            // 1. creating a socket to connect to the server
            requestSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2004);
            System.out.println("Connected to localhost in port 2004");
            // 2. get Input and Output streams
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(requestSocket.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            in = new ObjectInputStream(requestSocket.getInputStream());
            // 3: Communicating with the server
            try {
                message = (String) in.readObject();
                System.out.println("server>" + message);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            do {
                try {

                    message = (String) in.readObject();
                    System.out.println(message);
                    message = input.nextLine();
                    sendMessage(message);
                    message = (String) in.readObject();

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException classNot) {
                    System.err.println("data received in unknown format");
                }
            } while (!message.equals("FINISHED"));
        } catch (UnknownHostException unknownHost) {
            System.err.println("You are trying to connect to an unknown host!");
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // 4: Closing connection
            try {
                in.close();
                out.close();
                requestSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    void sendMessage(String msg) {
        try {
            out.writeObject(msg);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println("client>" + msg);
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Requester client = new Requester();
        client.run();
    }
}
```

The programs are basically meant to communicate with each other. The idea is that they each 'connect' with each other via sockets and the user should be able to enter something in the console window of Provider and have it echoed back onto the console of Requester. However, I am getting the following errors:

**Provider**

> java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: listen failed

**Requester**

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

(I can provide the rest of the errors if it would help in fixing the issue).

I have tried having the classes in the same project folder, in separate folders, and in different workspaces. I have also tried using Eclipse EE (Neon) and the SE (Oxygen). Recently, I have been having problems with ports and sockets (most notably with Tomcat and encountering the 'Cannot find free socket for debugger' in Eclipse). Would that have something to do with me being unable to run these programs?

Comment: Have you tried to reduce the issue to the minimal code in this case that should just be the connect statements. because it seems like you are not allowed to set up the socket in the provider. in which case the requester offcourse gets refused

Comment: Are you meant to have these two classes setup in two different instances of Eclipse? I'm new to using sockets in Java so I'm not too sure if I have it setup correctly in the first place. I have heard that having the two classes in the same folder in a case like this isn't right.

Comment: It shouldn't matter as long as you run them as separate instances.

Comment: This seems to work fine. Do you start the Provider first? If you start Requester first, you try to connect to a closed socket which would explain the Connection refused.

Comment: @Raven221221221 checked my firewall settings as one user suggested. Was running Requester by mistake first, so thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your firewall settings. I was having similar problems when trying to use sockets. Make sure any relevant resources aren't blocked.

You might also want to run the command:

> netstat -ano | findstr :2004

to check if that port is mistakenly in use already.